# What is the fastest way to get distinct rows in pyarrow table?

Tags: python, numpy, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am trying to get information about what are the distinct combinations of values in two of the columns in my pyarrow table.

What I am currently doing is:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
my_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(
  pd.DataFrame(
    {
      'col1':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 
      'col2':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,3],
      'col3':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    }
  )
)
a = [i.to_numpy().astype('str') for i in my_table.select(['col1', 'col2']).columns]
unique = np.unique(np.array(a), axis = 1)
```

Which returns the expected result of:

```
unique
>array([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
       ['1', '2', '1', '2', '3']], dtype='<U21')
```

but this is quite slow for larger tables and I would hope that there is a faster way?

Alternatively, what I'd really like to know, is when I am trying to write a partitioned dataset, how to know in advance to which directories will it write (i.e. which partitions have some data in my table)

EDIT:

it can be faster converting to pandas instead of multiple numpy arrays and then using `drop_duplicates()`:

```
my_table.select(['col1', 'col2']).to_pandas().drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Determining the uniques for a combination of columns (which could be represented as a StructArray, in arrow terminology) is not yet implemented in Arrow. So short term, I think converting to pandas and using `drop_duplicates()` is your best option.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Is there any known plan to implement it? Ticket, timeline?

Comment: General ticket is at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3978, no specific timeline, but hopefully in the coming months (there is work ongoing on groupby, which will also need this to be able to group on multiple columns)

Answer (score 3):

Support for encoding structs directly is tracked by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3978

In the meantime, here's a workaround which is computationally similar to pandas' unique-ing functionality, but avoids conversion-to-pandas costs by using `pyarrow`'s own compute kernels.

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc


def _dictionary_and_indices(column):
    assert isinstance(column, pa.ChunkedArray)

    if not isinstance(column.type, pa.DictionaryType):
        column = pc.dictionary_encode(column, null_encoding_behavior='encode')

    dictionary = column.chunk(0).dictionary
    indices = pa.chunked_array([c.indices for c in column.chunks])

    if indices.null_count != 0:
        # We need nulls to be in the dictionary so that indices can be
        # meaningfully multiplied, so we must round trip through decoded
        column = pc.take(dictionary, indices)
        return _dictionary_and_indices(column)

    return dictionary, indices


def unique(table):
    "produce a table containing only the unique rows from the input"
    if table.num_columns == 0:
        return None

    table = table.unify_dictionaries()

    dictionaries = []
    fused_indices = None

    for c in table.columns:
        dictionary, indices = _dictionary_and_indices(c)

        if fused_indices is None:
            fused_indices = indices
        else:
            # pack column's indices into fused_indices
            fused_indices = pc.add(
                pc.multiply(fused_indices, len(dictionary)),
                indices)

        dictionaries.append(dictionary)

    uniques = []

    # pc.unique can now be invoked on the single array of fused_indices
    fused_indices = pc.unique(fused_indices)

    for dictionary in reversed(dictionaries):
        # unpack the column's indices from fused_indices
        quotient = pc.divide(fused_indices, len(dictionary))
        remainder = pc.subtract(fused_indices,
                                pc.multiply(quotient, len(dictionary)))

        # decode this column's uniques
        uniques.insert(0, pc.take(dictionary, remainder))
        fused_indices = quotient

    return pa.Table.from_arrays(uniques, names=table.column_names)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_table = pa.table({
        'col1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
        'col2': [1,   1,   2,   2,   1,   1,   2,   3],
        'col3': [1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8],
    })

    assert unique(my_table.select(['col1', 'col2'])).equals(pa.table({
        'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
        'col2': [1,   2,   1,   2,   3],
    }))
```

Comment: Small note that this code will only work with the pyarrow development version (to be released in April as pyarrow 4.0)

Comment: Ha, so many reasons to look forward to the 4.0 already! :)

Comment: https://github.com/TomScheffers/pyarrow_ops/blob/main/pyarrow_ops/ops.py found this library with a drop_duplicates function for pyarrow tables as well. I will need to remember to benchmark these two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the aggregation function as well

```
table.group_by([<column_names>]).aggregate([])
```

Comment: This seems clear and nice, however I wonder if it is computationally efficient